# VSCode and Jupyter Notebooks: Automatic activation of virtual environment from selected kernel

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, virtual-environment

When working on a Python file with VSCode a new integrated terminal automatically activates the virtual environment from which I have chosen the Python interpreter. I find this to be very useful and I wanted to know if it's possible to do the same with Jupyter Notebooks.

If I select a specific virtual environment as my Jupyter kernel and open a new terminal, this will not activate the virtual environment. I thought there could be some command like `"jupyter.terminal.activateEnvironment": true` (if that makes sense?) but haven't been able to find anything.

Is there anything close to this? I'm very new to VSCode so some things I say might not be correct... Happy to learn more and thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "select a specific virtual environment as my Jupyter kernel"?
The procedure to install Jupyter in an environment is documented here: [Kernels for different environments](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html)

```
source activate myenv
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```

Finally, select the registered kernel "Python (myenv)" in VSCode and you're done.

Comment: I have this already set up and I installed Jupyter in the virtual environment without any problems. Thing is that if I open a folder from VSCode with a .ipynb file in it and select the kernel, a new integrated terminal won't activate the environment. This works however if I were using a .py file instead where I specify the interpereter.